# How to set active links based on querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

I need to make active the link referring to the URL of the page the user is viewing. That is not the problem, the problem is about the querystring in the URL; I tried different solutions looking at related answers and the only thing happening is that the link gets the color only when I click on it and immediately afterwards returns to the same colour as before.

I'm working on prestashop and this menu is a module installed and working perfectly if not for this little problem.

Here's the HTML (with javascript inside). The module is sent to an XML file for smarty to get and compile:

```
<div class="left_nav">
    <h3>VIAGGIA CON NOI</h3>
    <ul class="left_list">
        <li><a href="../../cms.php?id_cms=10">I nostri viaggi spiegati</a></li>
        <li><a href="../../cms.php?id_cms=11">Vostro viaggio su misura</a></li>
        <li><a href="../../cms.php?id_cms=12">Attività ed estensioni </a></li>
        <li><a href="../../cms.php?id_cms=17">Turismo accessibile</a></li>
        <li><a href="../../cms.php?id_cms=18">Collaborare con noi</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h3>DICONO DI NOI</h3>
    <ul class="left_list">
        <li><a href="../../cms.php?id_cms=19">I nostri viaggiatori</a></li>
        <li><a href="../../cms.php?id_cms=20">Stampa e altri media</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    $(function() {
        var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        $('ul.left_list li a[href*=" + filename + "]').each(function() {
            if (window.location.href.indexOf($(this).find('a').attr('href'))) {
                $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
// ]]></script>
```

Does anybody know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Noticed you forgot to escape:

```
 $('ul.left_list li a[href*="'+filename+'"]').each(function()
                             ^ here      ^here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this jquery code:

```
$(function()
 {
    $('.left_list li a').each(function(){
        loc= window.location.pathname;
        path=$(this).attr('href');
        alert(loc+'-'+path);

        if(loc==path)
        {
           alert('ok');
           $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

I've putted a couple alerts to see the difference between the href in the links and in the page, so that you can see where it differs. (I tested the code with different links and it works)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this: http://jsbin.com/amucep/2/edit

```
$(function() {
   var winurl = window.location.href;
   var url = winurl.substr(winurl.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

   $('ul.left_list li a').each(function() {
      $('ul.left_list li a[href$="'+url+'"]').addClass('active');   
   });
});
```